# How to illustrate the wizard flow when some steps are optional?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, workflow, wizard

I'm working on a wizard and have an issue about the flow illustration. I wan't to help the user as much as possible and think it would be confusing to make a flow with 6 steps where the last 3 is optional, - therefor i have the issue explained below:

The wizard have to include :

1. select columns
2. Add filters
3. Select if you wan't to "View" "Export to Excel" or "Save" the report

If view: 
Shows the report in the application

If Export to Excel:
Opens an Excel document with the data

If saving:
    3.a add name and discribtion 
    3.b Add excel template
    3.c Maybe add subscribtions

How can i present the flow for users when Step 3. determines whether the remaining steps are shown?

How can i make a layout that shows where in the flow users are when you do not know how far they want to go?

Is there another way of doing it?